# how to store callback return value in variable

Tags: protractor

```
  var finalPrice = checkout.checkTotalPrice(function(price){
             return price;
       });
```

I have above code. My callback is returning price. can anyone help How to store the returned price value in variable. Im using protractor Js

Comment: Can you give some more info about what you want to do? Protractor works with promises and only return a value when they are resolved, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195225/element-gettext-in-protractor/44195332#44195332) to see how to return values

Comment: thank you i used promise syntax and it worked :)

Comment: Nice that it works!